# sql file to csv file (or java objects) with java

Tags: java

I want to know if there is a way to acheive at least one of those purposes:

- from a **.sql** file get a `ResultList` with java without connection to database since we have a sql file.
- from a **.sql** file get a List of java Objects.
- from a **.sql** file get a csv file with Java.

Ps: I m not using any database management system it s only **.sql** file and Java .

Comment: If you are not using a database management system, then where is your data stored? You should elaborate a bit more. The question as is doesn't make sense because usually there is a database system involved in such a scenario.

Comment: the dump I have might come from many types of dbms (can be imported from oracle and an other time can can be imported from mysql)

Comment: It's not *impossible*, but it's *technically impossible*. Why do you think you need something like this?

Comment: It would be much, much easier to rely on standardized formats like XML or CSV for data exchange between different systems. Each database system should be able to dump the data in such a format. Or connect your Java application directly to the database via JDBC. If this all is not possible the safest way would be to import the dump into a database of the same type and then export it via JDBC. Sure, it would be possible to parse the INSERT statements manually. But then you have to handle all SQL dialect differences.